# VBA Script run on Worksheet change

Tags: excel, vba

I am having trouble getting a Excel VBA script to run anytime a change is made to the worksheet. I have a [Worksheet_Change](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.change) method but it doesn't seem to activate when a change is made to the worksheet.

```
Sub Calculate1(NUM As Integer)
    Dim EntryPrice As Double
    Dim ExitPrice As Double
    Dim Invested As Double
    Dim PL As Double
    Dim Margin As Double
    Dim InvestPercentage As Double
    
    If (Cells(NUM, 6).Value = "L" And IsNumeric(Cells(NUM, 7).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(NUM, 8).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(NUM, 10).Value)) Then
        EntryPrice = Cells(NUM, 7)
        ExitPrice = Cells(NUM, 8)
        Invested = Cells(NUM, 10)
        
        InvestPercentage = (Invested / EntryPrice) * 100
        PL = ((ExitPrice / 100) * InvestPercentage) - Invested
        Margin = PL / Invested
        
        If (PL > 0) Then
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
        Else
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        Cells(NUM, 11).Value = PL
        Cells(NUM, 12).Value = Margin
    ElseIf (Cells(NUM, 6).Value = "S" And IsNumeric(Cells(NUM, 7).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(NUM, 8).Value) And IsNumeric(Cells(NUM, 10).Value)) Then
        EntryPrice = Cells(NUM, 7)
        ExitPrice = Cells(NUM, 8)
        Invested = Cells(NUM, 10)
        
        InvestPercentage = (Invested / EntryPrice) * 100
        PL = ((ExitPrice / 100) * InvestPercentage) - Invested
        Margin = PL / Invested
        
        Cells(NUM, 11).Value = PL
        If (PL < 0) Then
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 10
            PL = -Abs(PL)
            Margin = -Abs(Margin)
        Else
            Cells(NUM, 11).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 11).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            Cells(NUM, 12).Font.Color = RGB(255, 255, 255)
            Cells(NUM, 12).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            PL = Abs(PL)
            Margin = Abs(Margin)
        End If
        
        Cells(NUM, 11).Value = PL
        Cells(NUM, 12).Value = Margin
    End If
End Sub
    
Sub CalculatePL()
    For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Calculate1 (i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Calculate1 (i)
    Next
End Sub

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Calculate1 (i)
    Next
End Sub
```

Am I implementing this completely wrong or is there something I need to change to get this method to activate?

Edit:
This code is in the module file that is associated with sheet1.[image]

I have also changed all of the references of Calculate to Calculate1 however the Worksheet_Change method is still not firing when the worksheet is changed.

Comment: The worksheet change event is basically fired when a cell or multiple cells are manually changed that is 1.) you enter a value in a cell, 2.) you copy/paste values or 3.) you use VBA to write values. It is often restricted to one cell, a few cells, or cells in one column. From the code, the candidates are the cells in columns 6, 7, 8, and 10, especially 6 which could have a drop-down. We cannot be sure. Which of these cells don't have formulas? Is this code in the sheet module of the worksheet whose code name is `Sheet1`? Please share any additional info by editing your post.

Comment: For me (us) to help you, it is crucial to know which of the cells `F3`. `G3`. `H3`, and `J3` contain values, and which contain formulas. You are not implementing this correctly. If you get it to work, it will end up in an endless loop and crash Excel. You need to use the `Target` argument and disable and then reenable events to use it safely. But a detailed explanation would be inappropriate for a comment. So, please share the information I asked for.

Comment: None of the cells contain formulas at the moment. The only formula type thing in the whole work book is the script in the question.

Comment: I don't know what exactly your function calculates so I would like to know what you plan with this `PL = -Abs(PL)` which makes no sense because `PL` is already negative (if `P<0`). I guess, if PL is negative so is Margin so again `Margin = -Abs(Margin)` makes no sense. Do you maybe want to return positive values no matter what? Also, you are dividing by `EntryPrice` from column `G` and it mustn't be `0`. How to account for that? Please elaborate on it.

Answer (score 0):

Calculate is a keyword in Excel VBA.  Try changing all references to Calculate1, to see if your sub routine is called as expected.

Also, your Worksheet_[event] subs must reside in the code module of the worksheet you are "changing" ...

Answer (score 0):

Moving the Worksheet_Change and Worksheet_Activate methods out of Module1 and into Sheet1 solved this issue for me.

Additionally I had to `Application.EnableEvents = False` and then set it as true again to stop Worksheet_Change entering an Infinite loop.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    For i = 3 To Sheet1.UsedRange.Rows.Count + 1
        Calculate1 (i)
    Next
    Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```